The problem of continuously refreshing data from the threading section of socketio.on in the flask back end in a multi-user environment
This is the first time I use flask as the backend, and I expect the data on my web page to be updated every 200s. So I use while true with time.sleep (200) in each module and transfer the data via socketio.on.
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    threading.Thread(target=get_realAlarm_data,daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=get_nrp_data,daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=get_groupwip_data,daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=get_pm_data,daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=process_eqpstatus_data,daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=mark_count, daemon=True).start()
    for module_name in MODULES:
        threading.Thread(target=send_data, args=(module_name,),daemon=True).start()

But my background log shows that sometimes the program gets caught in a non-stop refresh cycle and my pages die.
Take the get groupwip data module as an example. Other modules are similar.
def get_groupwip_data():
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            cached_data = get_cached_data('groupwip_data')
            # print(cached_data)
            if cached_data:
                logger.debug('Using cached groupwip_data')
                socketio.emit('update_getgroupwip', {'data': cached_data})
            else:
                logger.debug('Fetching groupwip_data from database')
                with engine.connect() as conn:
                    sql = """
                        SQL query
                        """

                    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
                    groupwip_list = [......] # data processing
                    
                    set_cached_data('groupwip_data', groupwip_list)
                    socketio.emit('update_getgroupwip', {'data': groupwip_list})
            time.sleep(200)

And I'm using the default server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        with open('notice.txt', 'r') as file:
            notice = file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass  
    socketio.run(app, debug=False, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)

I thought it was a threading problem, so I used the monkey patch in gevent. I want the user to see the current data display when they open the web page, and then my backend updates the data to the page every 200 seconds.
socketio = SocketIO(app,async_mode='gevent')

But, in fact, my program sometimes refreshes the data all the time, and this causes my page to freeze and not display any data.

So, you are starting at least seven threads here.  Are all of the threads trying to send data on the socket all at once?  I'm not surprised that explodes.  socketio is thread safe, but socket writes are not serialized.  Packets are going to be combined in that cute TCP way, and the other end has to untangle that.

Thanks for your reply Tim. I am a newcomer to using flask and developing web pages. After discovering the problem, I also tried to keep only one thread, but that thread started an infinite loop soon after. How should I deal with this situation?

There are an infinite number of reasons why code might go into an infinite loop.  Indeed, the code snippet above has an INTENTIONAL infinite loop.  We'll need more information about what's going on.

You're right. I wasn't accurate enough. What I want is for each part to be an infinite loop of updated data every 200 seconds. But what actually happens is that when the program goes crazy for some reason, you can see from the log that flask updates the data two or three times every second, which looks like it's not being controlled by time.sleep (200). Could the problem be caused by the user closing or refreshing the page, but their thread is not actually closed? Since I am a novice, I am not sure if there are any missing parts in the design of the program.

It should be the CLIENT that asks for data every 200 seconds, not the server pushing the data.  There is really no need for socketio here at all.  For something that only happens every three minutes, a simple AJAX request is more than sufficient.

Thank you so much for sharing your experience, tim. I send requests every 200 seconds via axios on vue and the program is no longer deranged. I don't know if the code in my flask part has a websocket problem or a thread problem.
